# Equational reasoning in Coq

Tags: coq, equality

I've been doing some exercises on Coq, and have stuck for the next problem:

> Let `T: Set` with 2 operations `f`, `g` on it. Suppose that these operations satisfy the following relations:
>
> 1. `f x (g x y) = x`
> 2. `g x (f x y) = x`
>
> Verify that `forall (x: T), f x x = x.`

So I've declared things:

```
Parameter T : Set.
Parameter f g: T -> T -> T.

Axiom ax_f: forall (x y: T), f x (g x y) = x.
Axiom ax_g: forall (x y: T), g x (f x y) = x.

Lemma l: forall (x: T), f x x = x.
Proof. intros. assert (Hf := ax_f x x). assert (Hg := ax_g x x).
```

But then I don't know what to do. I've tried rewriting the statement `f x x = x` via the axioms above, but that hadn't helped me. The only way to solve it that I found was the asserting `g x x = x`. With this in context, the problem solves quickly:

```
assert (g x x = x) as G.
2:{rewrite <- G at 2. assumption. }
```

But as one might notice, a new goal `g x x = x` was created, and thus nothing really changed so far. At this point, I don't really get how one solves this.

Can anyone give a hint on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As for a hint, have you thought about how to solve it informally with pen and paper?  You have figured out that if you can prove `g x x = x` then you can prove `f x x = x`, but now you have to figure out how to “catch your tail”.

Comment: I hesitate to give you more of a hint than that, but I and many others find that you can miss the forest for the trees when formalizing, and it is better to take a step back first and solve the problem informally before diving in to formalize it.

Comment: @JasonRute thanks for the hint! I was sitting with pen and paper before and this didn't help me, I was just burying myself into the symbolic things. After a bit of time, I've sat back and got the solution. 

Now I find this question pretty silly, should I consider removing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hint. Note that you have the following axiom:

```
Axiom ax_f: forall (x y: T), f x (g x y) = x.
```

and your goal is

```
f x x = x
```

Both are of the form `f x ? = x`.

You also have another axiom stating an equality with `x`.

---

Like Jason said, this is really a math question and you should try to figure it out on paper before moving to Coq.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, indeed, this not is pretty obvious, but for some reason I haven't came up with a thought that " `y := f x x` is the thing I need".